# Broken iPad (Screen)

Tags: ipad

I found donated iPad (Possibly a first generation, 16gb) at a donation center I work at. I have no idea what to do with it now. This could be a steal or just a piece of trash. Either way, I'm satisfied. My question is: Is this worth the fix? If so how much? Also, is there a tutorial to DIY this open to get more information about the break?

Additional info: When I plug the iPad into a power source, it blinks this "Error Screen" in 5 second increments.

[image: Broken iPad Screen]
[image: Error Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use iFixit when repairing my Apple stuff. From the looks of your picture, that is an original iPad (1st Generation).

If it turns out to be more trouble than it's worth, I would look into Gazelle, NextWorth, Itemcycle, SellYourMac, etc. Just go with whichever one will give you the most cash for it.

Sell iPad 1st Gen - Gazelle https://www.gazelle.com/ipad/ipad/1st-gen

Sell Your iPad - Itemcycle http://itemcycle.com/sell/ipad/ipad/1st-generation

Answer (score 1):

This site is great for identifying and purchasing parts if you want to fix the iPad yourself.

[http://www.ifixit.com/Device/iPad](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/iPad)

But, before you decide to spend a bunch of money, consider that you will probably encounter the [Activation Lock](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365).

Comment: Doesn't the iPad 1 only go to the firmware of IOS 5.1.1? If that's so, activation lock wouldn't exist, right?

Comment: You're absolutely right, @SamuelF. Activation Lock appears in iOS7. My bad!